# Error in a build plan for Docker with MQ

Tags: compiling, docker

We are trying to create a build plan with MQ inside a Docker Container using Ubuntu.  the `sudo` command doesn't work inside the Dockerfile so we can't use that solution found on the web.  Here are the errors we are getting:

```
build   16-May-2018 09:43:53    .[91mW: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (12: Cannot allocate memory)

build   16-May-2018 09:43:53    W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (12: Cannot allocate memory)
```

plus:

```
error   16-May-2018 09:43:54    The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     bash     ca-certificates     coreutils     curl     debianutils     findutils     grep     libc-bin     mount     passwd     procps     sed     tar     util-linux     apt-utils     bc     file     gawk     lsb-release     vim' returned a non-zero code: 100

simple  16-May-2018 09:43:54    Failing task since return code of [/bin/sh /opt/lforge/atlassian_data/bamboo_home/temp/MI-IWMFD-JOB1-20-ScriptBuildTask-6009970739082824316.sh] was 100 while expected 0

simple  16-May-2018 09:43:54    Finished task 'Build Docker Image' with result: Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

A member of my team (Darren) came up with a solution.  Docker uses a default of 2g.  Changed the docker command so it had parameters -m 4g  to get extra memory.